# Is it meaningful that one adds "-to-be" at the end of a word and coins a new word?

Tags: word-request

In one context, I read the beneath sentence:

> Some **authors-to-be** and new authors have trouble figuring out precisely how to leverage that book into speaking.

in which, the expression of "**authors-to-be**" was mind-boggling. I conjecture that its meaning is "authors have lived and worked so far". If so, my inquiry is it is possible that one appends "-to-be" at the end of a word to mint a neologism?

> For example, can (runner-to-be, athlete-to-be, singer-to-be, engineer-to-be, doctor-to-be, etc.) be minted?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a compound word like that, but the meaning is different.

An "author-to-be" is a person who will be an author in the future.  So you might say:

> My daughter is an author-to-be. Although she is only 10, she is already writing stories for her friends, and she says she wants to be the next J.K Rowling.

Comment: I was an answerer-to-be until I saw yours.